# Java - Why an exception is thrown on one run and doesn't on another ??

Tags: java, sorting, exception, quicksort

I'm using the quick sort algorithm to sort an arraylist and this is my code in QuickSort.java  :

```
public class QuickSort {

public ArrayList<Integer> quickSort(ArrayList<Integer> data , int low , int high){

    ArrayList<Integer> sortedData = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    if(low< high) {
        int pivotIndex = low; // Assume first element is the pivot
        int pivot = data.get(low);// The pivot value
        data.set(pivotIndex, data.get(high));// Swap pivot with last item
        data.set(high, pivot);
        int i = low - 1;
        int j = high;

        do {                
            do {i++;} while (data.get(i)< pivot);

            do {j--;} while (data.get(j)> pivot); //line 35
            if (i < j) {
                int temp = data.get(i);
                data.set(i, data.get(j));
                data.set(j, temp);

            }

        } while (i < j);

        data.set(high, data.get(i));  // Put the pivot back in the middle
        data.set(i, pivot);

        quickSort(data, low, i - 1);// Recursive sort left list
        quickSort(data, i + 1 ,high);// Recursive sort right list
    }

    sortedData = data;

    return sortedData ; 
}
}
```

and in the main class :

```
// sort random data with quick sort

    QuickSort q = new QuickSort();

    ArrayList<Integer> quickSortedD = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    System.out.println("randomD before q s "+ randomD );
    int low = 0;
    int high = randomD.size() -1 ;

    System.out.println("high :  " + high);

    quickSortedD = q.quickSort(randomD ,low, high); // low is the first element and high is the last element in the arraylist

    System.out.println("quickSortedD" + quickSortedD);
```

randomD is arraylist that's randomly generated with each run but with fixed size 1500 .

**The problem is :** When I run the file, sometimes it throws exceptions and sometimes it build successfully !!

**Thrown Exceptions :**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(ArrayList.java:422)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:435)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:35)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:48)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:48)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:48)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:48)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:48)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:48)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:48)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:48)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:48)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:48)
at sortingtechniques.QuickSort.quickSort(QuickSort.java:48)
at sortingtechniques.SortingTechniques.main(SortingTechniques.java:104)
```

/home/gfdg/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

QuickSort.java:35 :

```
do {j--;} while (data.get(j)> pivot);
```

QuickSort.java:48 :

```
quickSort(data, low, i - 1);// Recursive sort left list
```

SortingTechniques.java:104 :

```
quickSortedD = q.quickSort(randomD ,low, high);
```

**Why does this happen and how can I fix it ??**

Comment: Take a debugger. See what happens. j can easily go to negative since you don’t check that. That will cause an issue.

Comment: looks like that's ^^^ the case: "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1"

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html

Comment: yes it now works after checking j : do {j--;} while (j>=0 && data.get(j)> pivot); thanks @SamiKuhmonen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that I didn't put restrictions on {j --;}

so it sometimes continue decrementing it to be -1

it now works after changing it to be :

```
do {j--;} while (j>=0 && data.get(j)> pivot);
```